# Picking a random variable from a pdf in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am having some strange bug, which I cannot grasp where it comes from. I am writing it in js in Google Script environment.

```
function tester() {
  var pdf = [[0,5],[1,5],[2,40],[3,50]]; // some pdf as a 2d array
  var tuple = [0,0,0,0]; //the resulting pdf from the test
  var rand = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i<100; i++){ //100 times initialize a random variable and then catch the result into the tuple 
    rand = getRandomN(pdf);
    if (rand==0){tuple[0]+=1} //if the outcome==0 then add 1 to the first element of the tuple
       else if (rand==1){tuple[1]+=1}
       else if (rand==2){tuple[2]+=1}
       else if (rand==3){tuple[3]+=1}
  }

  Logger.log(tuple);
}
```

`getRandomN(pdf)` returns one outcome according to the pdf

The problem is that the tuple always returns all zeros with 1 at some of the places. It looks like the randomizer works just fine, but looping is gone through only once.
Does anyone have a hint?

UPDATE:

```
function getRandomN(pdf) {
  var result = 0;
  var rand = getRandomInt(0,10000)/100;

  for (var i=1; i<pdf.length; i++){
    pdf[i][1] = pdf[i][1] + pdf[i-1][1];

    }

  if (pdf[pdf.length-1][1] != 100){return undefined}

  //Logger.log(rand);
  for (var i=0; i<pdf.length; i++){
    if (rand<=pdf[i][1]){result=pdf[i][0]; break}

  }
  Logger.log(pdf);
return result;
}
```

And the standard function from the Mozilla

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

Comment: where is getRandomN show this part also if possible.

Comment: I will add it right now. It's just that it works just fine if I simply test it without a loop, but the loop kinda gets skipped.

Comment: Your loop looks fine to me... did you write getRandomN()? can we see the code for that? 
Also, if you know that getRandomN()will only return values that match up to the indices of your tuple, you could replace the whole interior of the loop with one line:
`tuple[getRandomN(pdf)] += 1;`

Comment: Updated. I just decided to write this `tester() ` to simply test if the randomizer works correctly on a larger number of trials, hence, hard-coded it without much thought. Thanks for the hint though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is:

```
  if (pdf[pdf.length-1][1] != 100){return undefined;}
```

here you are returning undefined if you `return 0 or any of rand first index` then it will display proper `tuple` and you can see the loop count.

try running this:

```js
     function tester() {
       var pdf = [[0,5],[1,5],[2,40],[3,50]]; // some pdf as a 2d array
       var tuple = [0,0,0,0]; //the resulting pdf from the test
       var rand = 0;
    
       for (var i = 0; i<100; i++){ //100 times initialize a random variable and then catch the result into the tuple 
         rand = getRandomN(pdf);
         tuple[rand] += 1;
       }
    
       console.log(tuple);
       document.write(tuple);
     }
    
     function getRandomN(pdf) {
       var result = 0;
       var rand = getRandomInt(0,10000)/100;
      // console.log(rand);
       for (var i=1; i<pdf.length; i++){
         pdf[i][1] = pdf[i][1] + pdf[i-1][1];
    
         }
    
       if (pdf[pdf.length-1][1] != 100){return 0;}//return any of 0,1,2,3 to test your code.
    
       for (var i=0; i<pdf.length; i++){
         if (rand<=pdf[i][1]){result=pdf[i][0]; break}
    
       }
     //  console.log(pdf);
     return result;
     }
    
     function getRandomInt(min, max) {
       return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
     }
     tester();
```

Comment: Wow. thank you Suchit! But why is it like this? I am just checking in this snippet if the sum of all probabilities of a pdf equals to 100, i.e. the last element of the cdf, which is named pdf because I did not rename it, but rewrote the pdf. I commented out the section and it works. But why?

Comment: I think I know why. Because the scope of pdf is exactly global and I am changing it within the getRandomN(pdf), hence, it is increasing all the time, and after the first run it gets updated and I am calculating already from a new pdf, where the last element of the pdf (i.e. cdf) will never be equal to 100.

Comment: I wouldn't have been able to solve it without you Suchit. Thanks for your hint!

Answer (score 0):

I think I know why. Because the scope of pdf is exactly global within the `tester()` and I am changing it within the `getRandomN(pdf)`, hence, it is increasing all the time, and after the first run it gets updated and I am calculating already from a new pdf, where the last element of the pdf (i.e. cdf) will never be equal to 100.
UPDATE:
Just if you are interested in the correct code that is working. The part of mapping pdf to cdf is not the most beautiful one. I'd appreciate improvement hints, but it works just fine. Kudos to the contributors for pointing into the right direction.

```
function getRandomN(pdf) {
  var result = 0;
  var rand = getRandomInt(0,10000)/100;
  var cdf = [];

  //construct the cdf
  for (var i=1; i<pdf.length; i++){
    //handle the first unchanged element
    cdf[0]=[];
    cdf[0][1] = pdf[0][1];
    cdf[0][0] = pdf[0][0];

    cdf[i]=[];
    cdf[i][1] = pdf[i][1] + cdf[i-1][1];
    cdf[i][0] = pdf[i][0];//add all outcomes to the array's first column
    }

  if (cdf[cdf.length-1][1] != 100){return undefined}

  //Logger.log(rand);
  for (var i=0; i<cdf.length; i++){
    if (rand<=cdf[i][1]){result=cdf[i][0]; break}
    }

  //Logger.log(cdf);
return result;
}
```